# SQLite error on table creation with index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, ddl

I am trying to make SQLite3 database with PHP that has an index.

[There is an example on dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) that makes an index like the one below.

```
$db = new SQLite3(':memory:');

$db->exec("CREATE TABLE sales (
    kitchen_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amount_name VARCHAR(255),
    amount NUMERIC(15,2),
    name_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    flag_total TINYINT(1),
    INDEX kitchen_value_key (kitchen_name,name_key)
);");
```

I have run the query in an [online parser](http://sql.phpmix.com/) and it is coming back as valid MySQL.

But I keep getting the error:

`SQLite3::exec(): near "INDEX": syntax error`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try creating the table first, and then adding the INDEX separately. "CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS kitchen_value_key ON sales (kitchen_name,name_key)";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed valid MySQL syntax, but you aren't using MySQL, you're using SQLite, which is a different RDBMS.

SQLite just doesn't support the syntax for inlining index definitions in the table definitions, so you'll have to resort to using two separate statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sales (
    kitchen_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amount_name VARCHAR(255),
    amount NUMERIC(15,2),
    name_key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    flag_total TINYINT(1)
);

CREATE INDEX kitchen_value_key ON sales(kitchen_name,name_key);
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7e9c6)**

Answer (score 2):

SQLITE is not mysql. They have very different syntactic rules at points

I'm assuming you want to create a normal index on the SQLITE table.
Put the index creation in a seperate statement from the table creation.

You should follow the instructions on

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS kitchen_value_key ON sales (kitchen_name, name_key)
```